# Setting trimmed value into Range.Value

Tags: excel, vba

I attempting to remove leading spaces from my code by using the trim function. Whenever I try to set a trimmed value to range.Value, a get an error because of a type mismatch

In my original code, I had a line that simply said cell.value = Trim(cell.value). After this caused an error, a wrote a simpler code with the line that was giving me an issue (=TIME' during the first check with command status.) This simple code shows the same error, so I am not sure of the reason

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As String

    Set x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet483").Range("A105")
    y = x.Value
    y = Trim(y)
    x.Value = y
End Sub
```

Comment: No repro. What is the value of `x`?

Comment: It's the specific cell that it is set to

Comment: What is the text in that cell?

Comment: "                                     =TIME' during the first check with command status." with about 35 spaces at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Excel attempts to use `=TIME` as a formula; I'm assuming that's not what you want.

Change the range's formatting to *Text* to write the trimmed text back to the cell.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As String

    Set x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet483").Range("A105")
    y = x.Value
    y = Trim(y)
    x.NumberFormat = "@"
    x.Value = y

End Sub
```

If you don't want to change the formatting, then perhaps something like this:

```
y = x.Value
y = "'" & Trim(y)
x.Value = y
```